# Making API connection from local drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I am trying to access website APIs from my local drive to work with their data.  I followed the JSON doc on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) and it worked great. I can access and get the same data as shown in the doc with the code below.  However when I change to a different website's API, I get an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error. For example if I use  (http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts).

After doing some search online, it seems to have to do with CORS setup on some servers.  I read through the CORS doc (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) but still having trouble with it.

Some search results also mentioned a work around like using proxy but I am reluctant to use it as it seems unwieldy.  I also tried Jquery and AJAX but I still get the same error when it tries to open the request.

```
   <script>
var header = document.querySelector('header');
var section = document.querySelector('section');
var requestURL = 'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json';   

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseTYPE = 'json';
request.send();

request.onload=function() {
    var superHeroes = JSON.parse(request.response);  //Parse the files
    populateHeader (superHeroes);
    showHeroes(superHeroes);
}
```

...

When I say local drive, I mean I saved the html code in a notepad file on my C:\document drive and running the file there. 
Any advice?  Thanks.

Comment: the code you've shown works fine, even when loading `file:///`

Comment: `but still having trouble with it` - thing with CORS is, it's reponse headers sent by the server - if a server doesn't send CORS headers in the response, then there's nothing for you to do about it

Comment: Yes the code shown works fine.  But if I change the var requestURL to a different URL like "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts" then I get this error in IE10:  [CORS] The origin 'file://' did not find 'file://' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin  resource at 'http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts'.

Comment: And this on firefox: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://null’).

Comment: yes, because not all sites allow CORS

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers agree with the server CORS policy by default. Developers sometimes disable security protections to test things out. Be sure to turn it back on for normal browsing.

With [Chrome on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19317888/5211891), this flag enabled that API to work for me:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

This works well in a shortcut for special uses.

More info on bypassing CORS in Chrome and FireFox here:
https://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-bypass-cors-errors-on-chrome-and-firefox-for-testing/

Update: In Firefox, the about:config option to disable "strict_origin_policy" is limited. So to get this working, you can try the [CORS Everywhere add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/). This worked for me on Firefox 52.8.

[image: CORS Everywhere screenshot]

The CORS Everywhere icon will toggle green after you click it, which enables CORS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried disabling that flag in FireFox as described on that website but I still get the same error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://null’).

Comment: Have you tried the "CORS Everywhere" add on for FireFox? It worked with quotesondesign when I installed it. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the responses.  I'll try the add-on later.